# Is it possible to run protractor as a module from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to trigger a protractor test by sending a http request, with the response containing the results of the test, as in the code snippet below. Is it possible to use protractor as a module to allow me to do that?

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request,response)
{
    //call to execute protractor test
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("This should contain the test results");
    response.end();
}
).listen(8080);

console.log("Listening on port 8080");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run it as a child shell process

Here is the documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

But protractor with many E2E-tests runs quite slowly (in my case around 4 minutes). Are you sure you want to sit down and wait for result. I would recommend to organize this asynchronously. So the request will only a schedule protractor running and return job ID, and you can fetch job ID status from time to time.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I noticed protractor tests to be quite slow as well, organizing asynchronously is a good idea. I'll try the child process track.